# Best way to add logo to a photo: Illustrator vs Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I understand that Adobe Illustrator is better for making logos because they can be re-sized to any size. I also understand that Adobe Photoshop is better for actually cutting/adding effects to photos.

However, what if I want to take a photo, add effects to it and also then add my logo to it that I designed in AI?

Should I create/add effects to my photo in photoshop and then import the logo as a stamp from AI (or something like that)? Or should I do the project in AI by importing the photo I edited from photoshop?

If done in AI, I was thinking to make my logo into a symbol and then just reuse it.

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming but about using specific graphic tools. Better asked on [Graphic Design Stackexchange](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/): "Graphic Design Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for Graphic Design professionals, students, and enthusiasts."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer is spot on. Create your logo in Illustrator so you can use it anywhere and add it in PS since the photo is a raster image and is not infinitely scalable anyway.

Comment: So once I drag my AI logo into photoshop, does it still stay a vector? Can I select the AI logo's size without loosing quality when I paste it into PS?

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your photo in PS and then drag and drop the logo from AI. It will be a smart object in PS, resize it and place it where you need. PS is better at handling photo size and effects.